# Convert an array of objects into an array of DTOs

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently working on a HMS project (Hotel Management System). I am currently stucked in implementing a DTO based functionality in Symfony 5. The following from below is my HotelMapper.php file where I would like to build a method which transforms the Array of Hotels into an Array of DTOs so I can pass them in the Hotel Controller later on and for this I would like to use the objects from the `dtoToHotel()` function. I already created the DTO (setters & getters).

```
namespace App\Transformer;

use App\DTO\HotelDTO;
use App\Entity\HotelEntity;

class HotelMapper
{
    public $hotel;
    public function dtoToHotel(HotelDTO $hotelDTO, Hotel $hotel) : HotelEntity
    {
        $hotel->setId($hotelDTO->getId());
        $hotel->setName($hotelDTO->getName());
        $hotel->setLocation($hotelDTO->getLocation());
        $hotel->setEmployees($hotelDTO->getEmployees());
        $hotel->setAvailability($hotelDTO->getAvailability());
        $hotel->setFacility($hotelDTO->getFacility());
        $hotel->setPhoto($hotelDTO->getPhoto());
        $hotel->setDescription($hotelDTO->getDescription());
        $hotel->setEarnings($hotelDTO->getEarnings());
    }

    public function hotelToDto(HotelEntity $hotel)
    {
        return HotelDTO(
          $hotel->getId(),
          $hotel->getName(),
          $hotel->getLocation(),
          $hotel->getEmployees(),
          $hotel->getAvailability(),
          $hotel->getFacility(),
          $hotel->getPhoto(),
          $hotel->getDescription(),
          $hotel->getEarnings()
        );
    }
    
    public function transformHotelsArrayToDTO()
    {
        /* Code here */
    }
}
```

The code from below is my **HotelController** where I would like to update the following line `$hotels = $this->hotelRepository->findAll()` inside the `showAllHotels()` function by passing the DTO in here. Any help is much appreciated!

```
class HotelController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var HotelRepository
     */
    public $hotelRepository;

    public function __construct(HotelRepository $hotelRepository)
    {
        $this->hotelRepository = $hotelRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @Route (path="/", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('index/index.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route (path="/hotel-management", methods={"GET"})
     */
    // It does populate the table with the hotels from the DB
    public function showAllHotels(): Response
    {
        $hotels = $this->hotelRepository->findAll();

        return $this->render('hotel-management/hotel-management.html.twig', array('hotels' => $hotels));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject HotelMapper transformer to your controller and then pass findAll's result to this function:

```
public function transformHotelsArrayToDTO(array $items): array
{
    if (empty($items) or is_null($items)) {
        return [];
    }

    return array_map([$this, 'hotelToDto'], $items);
}
```